# validating last two characters to follow a pattern

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I have a string `abcdefgh`,

i want to check if the last two characters are alpha numeric/alphabets but not numeric

i.e.  it can end in `a1`, `1a`, `aa` but not `11`

are there any regex gurus who can chipin

The regex should return the below results for the strings

abcd  - True
abc1d - True
abcd1 - True
abc12 - false

Comment: This is confusing: `11` *is* a string of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: well that is my weird requirement though NN is alphanumeric in my case i should not allow it

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
^.*(\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](\d|[a-zA-Z]))$
```

[Online regex tool demo here](http://regexr.com?382qh).

Meaning:

```
^                       the beginning of the string
.*                      any character except \n (0 or more times)
(                        
 \d[a-zA-Z]             a digit (0-9) followed by any character of a to z, A to Z
 |                      OR
 [a-zA-Z]               any character of a to z, A to Z followed by
 (\d|[a-zA-Z])          a digit or any character of a to z, A to Z
)                         
$                       end of the string
```

Notice this matches the whole string, not only the two last chars, having those at the matched group **one**.

Comment: No, that doesn't match `aa`.

Comment: @PeterWestlake you're right. Fixed.

Comment: Note - `(\d|[a-zA-Z])` = `[\da-zA-Z]`.

Comment: it passes for a1, 1a  but fails for aa

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq yeah, it did, but I edited. See the updated answer.

Comment: yes this works finally

Answer (score 1):

So, a letter and a digit, or a digit and a letter, or two letters?

```
([a-zA-Z]\d|\d[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])$
```

Depending on the regex system you're using, you can also use character classes such as `:alpha:`, but this one will work for all of them. Some regex syntaxes need a backslash in front of the parentheses and/or pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^.*[A-Za-z].|.[A-Za-z]$
```

[Online test](http://regex101.com/r/zY3oG2)

Comment: No, that matches things that aren't digits, like `a!`.

Comment: @PeterWestlake I'm fully aware of this. But the question is highly unclear. The word *digit* is not present in the question.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Agreed that it's unclear (should be closed unless / until clarified), but "alphanumeric" does appear in the question, which `a!` isn't.

Comment: @Dukeling Right, but `11` is alphanumeric *and* invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
^.*([a-zA-Z]{2}|(\d[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z]\d))$
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sT1cW6)**

**EXPLANATION:**

[image]